# Javascript change view after logging out of third party services - Gmail Add-ons

Tags: javascript, gmail-addons

I am building a gmail add-on connecting to non-Google services. I want to change the view after logging out of the third party services using Oauth2. Can anyone suggest me a solution? Regard.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function to hanlde logout like:

```
 function handleSignOutClick(event) {
   gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
   window.location.href = '/path'; //relative to domain
 }
```

Comment: i tried with your suggest but not run, it meet error signOut() not found and variable window undefined. As i know variable document, window not support in script.google.com

Comment: [Document oauth2](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2). I am using Oauth2 for connect to third party that suggest reset() function to logging out, i need after logging out load new view for add-on.